# How to do the equivlent of pd.Series.str.count() on whole DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Goal: Count the number of Plaintiffs and Defendants but NOT the number of Counter Defendants or Counter Plaintiffs. Do not count NaNs.

Assume ~200 rows and up to 100 columns named similarly to the example below.

Data:

```
    cl_parties_1_name   cl_parties_1_party_types_0_name   cl_parties_1_party_types_10_name  cl_parties_1_party_types_12_name    cl_parties_1_party_types_1_name   cl_parties_1_party_types_2_name
0   Jason Boyd          NaN                               Counter Defendant                  NaN                                Plaintiff                         NaN
1   Roberto Santana     Plaintiff                         NaN                                NaN                                NaN                               Counter Defendant
2   Raymond Satterfield Counter Defendant                 NaN                                NaN                                Plaintiff                         NaN
```

Desired output:

```
Plaintiffs = 3
Defendants = 0
```

Backstory: I have this mess of nested JSON which is delivered paginated from the API. I have unnested it and appended the pages together.

This leaves me with 100s of rows and potentially a few dozen columns.

EDIT: I know this has been asked several times about Serieses but I couldn't find it for a whole Dataframe or how to do it on all columns in a semi efficient way. Ill need to look at about 10,000 of these ~100x~200 DataFrames.

Comment: You can try df.eq('Plaintiff').sum().sum() or df.stack().str.count('Plaintiff').sum()

Comment: @Vaishali that looks like it might be better as an answer than a comment

Comment: @G.Anderson, I was searching for a dupe, surprising couldn't find any :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the exact string in each cell and sum over axis 0 and 1.

```
df.eq('Plaintiff').sum().sum()
```

Using Numpy sum would be more efficient,

```
np.sum(df.eq('Plaintiff').values)

3

np.sum(df.eq('Defendants').values)

3
```

Comment: df.stack().str.count('Defendant').sum() counted the "Counter Defendant" cells but np.sum(df.eq('Defendant').values) works perfectly